# Mod Rewrite Text after Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a two pages:
Member.php
Member-likes.php

I'm trying to make the URL structure this:

**www.domain.com/member**     = www.domain.com/member.php
**www.domain.com/member/Sam**  =  www.domain.com/member/?userID=Sam
**www.domain.com/member/Sam/likes**  =  www.domain.com/member-likes.php?userID=David

Right now my htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^explore/(.*) palette.php?colID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^explore explore.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile profile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/likes/?$ member-likes.php?userID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/?$ member.php?userID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^member/? member.php [L]

RewriteRule ^login login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [L]
```

I've read up on so many documents, I'm probably using the flags wrong or something? My main problem is I have no idea what I'm trying to do is called making searching difficult!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use line start/end anchors:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/likes/?$ member-likes.php?userID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/?$ member.php?userID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^member/?$ member.php [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, strange - It still doesn't work, maybe because of my existing settings? I've attached them to my first post.. Thanks Anubhava